# Round only specific columns of matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

i am getting some output in Matlab as given below

```
   4.4033       1.2575       3.1456       2.9319
   7.8755       1.9982        4.873       2.2627
   5.3249       2.1254       2.3472       3.3858
   7.0089       2.7482       4.5202         4.73
```

i want to get output having first and second column as integer. I tried round function but i got following result

```
4       1       3     3
8       2       5     2
5       2       2     3
7       3       5     5
```

how do i get output as following form

```
   4   1   3.1456    2.9319
   8   2   4.873     2.2627
   5   2   2.3472    3.3858
   7   3   4.5202    4.73
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use linear indexing to select the columns you want to round, as simple as that:

```
A(:,1:2) = round( A(:,1:2) )
```

Comment: @SIMEL thanks for the edit, I've completely overseen this.